# Convolution Neural Network in torch. Error when training the network

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch

I am trying to base my Convolution neural network upon the following tutorial:

https://github.com/torch/tutorials/tree/master/2_supervised

The issue is that my images are of different dimensions than those used in the tutorial. (3x200x200). Also I have only two classes.

The following are the changes that I made :

Changing the dataset to be loaded in 1_data.lua.

```
nfeats = 3
width = 200
height = 200
ninputs = nfeats*width*height
```

and

```
nclass,noutputs
```

in 3_loss.lua and 4_train.lua.

My model is the same as that being trained in the tutorial. For Convenience I'll put the code below :

```
  model = nn.Sequential()

  -- stage 1 : filter bank -> squashing -> L2 pooling -> normalization
  model:add(nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(nfeats, nstates[1], filtsize, filtsize))
  model:add(nn.Tanh())
  model:add(nn.SpatialLPPooling(nstates[1],2,poolsize,poolsize,poolsize,poolsize))
  model:add(nn.SpatialSubtractiveNormalization(nstates[1], normkernel))

  -- stage 2 : filter bank -> squashing -> L2 pooling -> normalization
  model:add(nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(nstates[1], nstates[2], filtsize, filtsize))
  model:add(nn.Tanh())
  model:add(nn.SpatialLPPooling(nstates[2],2,poolsize,poolsize,poolsize,poolsize))
  model:add(nn.SpatialSubtractiveNormalization(nstates[2], normkernel))

  -- stage 3 : standard 2-layer neural network
  model:add(nn.Reshape(nstates[2]*filtsize*filtsize))
  model:add(nn.Linear(nstates[2]*filtsize*filtsize, nstates[3]))
  model:add(nn.Tanh())
  model:add(nn.Linear(nstates[3], noutputs))
```

I get the following error when I run the doall.lua file :

```
 ==> online epoch # 1 [batchSize = 1]   
 /home/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/Tensor.lua:462: Wrong size for view. Input size: 64x47x47. Output size: 64x1600
 stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'error'
 /home/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/Tensor.lua:462: in function 'view'
 /home/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Reshape.lua:49: in function 'updateOutput'
 /home/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:29: in function 'forward'
 4_train.lua:160: in function 'opfunc'
 /home/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/optim/sgd.lua:43: in function 'optimMethod'
 4_train.lua:184: in function 'train'
 doall.lua:77: in main chunk
 [C]: in function 'dofile'
 [string "_RESULT={dofile('doall.lua' )}"]:1: in main chunk
 [C]: in function 'xpcall'
 /home/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:630: in function 'repl'
 .../torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:185: in main chunk
 [C]: at 0x00406670
```

I have been stuck at this for over a day now. Please help.

Comment: I am using the following kernel :
image.gaussian1D(7). However I do not know the input image size I should keep to avoid hitting corners while convolving. Could someone please explain the logic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the convolutional neural network from this tutorial has been made to work with a **fixed size input resolution** of 32x32 pixels.

Right after the 2 convolutional / pooling layers you obtain 64 feature maps with a 5x5 resolution. This gives an input of 64x5x5 = 1,600 elements for the following fully-connected layers.

As you can see in the tutorial there is a dedicated *reshape* operation that transforms the 3D input tensor into a 1D tensor with 1,600 elements:

```
-- nstates[2]*filtsize*filtsize = 64x5x5 = 1,600
model:add(nn.Reshape(nstates[2]*filtsize*filtsize))
```

When you work with a higher resolution input you produce higher resolution output feature maps, here a 200x200 pixels input gives 64 output feature maps of size 47x47. This is why you obtain this *wrong size* error.

So you need to adapt the reshape and following linear layers accordingly:

```
model:add(nn.Reshape(nstates[2]*47*47))
model:add(nn.Linear(nstates[2]*47*47, nstates[3]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never realized that there is a neural network at the end of this model.  I have another question : Given any image I want to classify it as 'A sunflower' and 'Not A sunflower'. How can this be done ? what should I keep the second class as ? A dataset of all the images -{ sunflower }? But this sounds computationally infeasible. Is this possible with the existing framework that I have ? Kindly Help.